# Dictionary max three values

Tags: python, dictionary, key, return-value

I want to make a program that will find the maximum 3 values in a dictionary, then print their keys in order. E.g. for:

```
people_dict = {"person_1": 3, "person_2": 6, "person_3": 6, "person_4": 1}
```

I would like it to print out a list of only the top 3 people e.g. `["person_2", "person_3", "person_1"]`.

Comment: OK. What do you have so far?

Comment: So what have you tried so far, and what is the problem with it? Are you aware of [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)?

Comment: `sorted(people_dict,key=people_dict.get,reverse=True)[:3]`

Comment: Oh my god that worked perfectly thank you. My coursework is complete. :)